# Display variable (Int) in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, label

I want to show the page number of a PDF. The current page is saved in `Int currentpage;`. I created a Label like `Label pagenumber = new Label();`. I tried with `pagenumber.textProperty().bind(currentpage);` but then Eclipse ask me to change currentPage in `ObservableValue <? extends String >`. I think it's really easy to do what I want, but I'm very new about JavaFX. Sorry, for the easy question.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use properties and bindings I recommend reading the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was really easy.

I write the solution, maybe it could be helpful to someone very new, like me , in JavaFX.

```
pagenumber.setText("" +currentPage);
```

or in general

```
Label.setText("" +intValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
pagenumber.setText(Integer.toString(currentPage));
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation to your post that talks about how the code works. This allows new developers to understand what the code does.